Im trying to get user input (string) from a function, and then set a variable in my main function to their input. in C
int main(void){
int *placeholder;
char userID[10] = "";

placeholder = getIdentity();
userID = *placeholder;
}

int getIdentity(){
    static char userin[] = "";
    printf("What is your ID?");
    scanf("%s", userin);
    return(&userin);
}

Ive been messing around with pointers and Ive been looking into how to return a pointer from a function. All of the information online uses integer values and they worked fine for me but when i tried it with a string i get a lot of errors and cant find out how to make it work.

static char userin[] = ""; userin has a 1 char capacity - enough for a null terminator only. It is not big enough to handle any input. Your getIdentity() claims to return an int, not a string.

@AviBerger i thought if its returning an address it would have to be an int still

pointers are not ints. ints are not pointers. Ages of C programmers have struggled with that, sometimes doing things that appear to work . . . until something changes enough that it doesn't anymore.

Many issues:

static char userin[] = ""; is only one char long. C language does not automatically allocate the required memory
function is returning int not char *
No function prototype.
The code in main makes no sense
No error checking

#include <stdio.h>

char *getIdentity(void);

int main(void)
{
    char *placeholder = getIdentity();

    if(placeholder) printf("UserID is '%s'\n", placeholder);
    else printf("Something gone wrong\n");
}

char *getIdentity(void)
{
    static char userin[30];
    printf("What is your ID?");
    return fgets(userin, sizeof(userin), stdin);
}


Note that in the ordinary course of events (less than 29 characters entered), the return value will include a newline.  It might be worth removing it when present.  It might be an idea to gobble the rest of the line if the newline is not present.

I've made some changes to get this running.  getIdentity() now returns a char pointer to the static char array userin, to which we've added some space (can hold 20 chars now).  Please note that a char pointer is a valid address -- it simply points to a char array rather than an int or some other type.  Always ensure the pointer type (char, int...) matches the type it points to.
userID in main() is now a char pointer, and it is used to receive the char pointer returned by getIdentity().
Finally, we print the char array populated in getIdentity().
UPDATE: please note the change to the scanf() formatting -- we've added 19 to stop scanning at 19 chars, leaving room for the trailing NUL for a buffer size of 20 (thanks Fe2O3).  Also updated/added error handling thanks to comments from Jonathan Leffler.
You can see that the scanning stops nicely at 19 chars via the updated runnable code here.
#include <stdio.h>

char *getIdentity()
{
    static char userin[20] = "";
    printf("What is your ID?: ");
    if(scanf("%19s", userin) == 1)
    {
        return (userin);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("scanf() has failed!");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *userID = getIdentity();

    if(userID)
        printf("\nuserID:  %s\n", userID);
    else
        printf("\nFAIL\n");

    return 0;
}


Should ensure userin[] does not overrun for user id "rumplestiltskin123456"...

See How to prevent scanf() causing a buffer overfow in C? — that should be if (scanf("%19s", userin) == 1) return userin; else { …handle error… }.

@Fe2O3 -- 100% -- I have updated for the world and credited you, thx!

@JonathanLeffler  - 100% -- yes, these thoughts are added, and thx your kind input.
